# Hystrix queue size for HystrixObservableCommand?

Tags: java, hystrix

When your Hystrix command extends from `HystrixCommand` you can specify a queue size for the thread pool like this:

```
..
.andThreadPoolPropertiesDefaults(HystrixThreadPoolProperties.Setter()
                            .withMaxQueueSize(10)
                            .withQueueSizeRejectionThreshold(10));
```

But when extending from `HystrixObservableCommand` there's (obviously) no threadpool to configure a queue size for. But what if you still want to allow for queued requests for a `HystrixObservableCommand` when the `ExecutionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests` reaches its limit?

1. Does Hystrix provide any support for this or is this something you have to roll yourself?
2. If the latter then how would you implement this in an idiomatic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hystrix parallel processing is handled by a blocking queue and the Hystrix  implementation it seems will reject request when the blocking size is reached (and execute the fallback method). It does not seem like there is a way around this or specifically detect if the request was rejected due to queue size.

You can see this in the flow in step 5. They thread pool or semaphore reject fallback to the default. It does not have any options to configure any additional blocking queue.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Netflix/Hystrix/images/hystrix-command-flow-chart.png

I'm not sure how you would work around this, seems like a limitation/feature of the Hystrix library